# How can I check if all of my ajax request(s) are complete?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have three `<select>` inputs on my form. Each select has an option which is a zero value.

If the value is zero, I do not want to make an ajax request. If the selected option *does* have a value, then I do want to make the request.

Here is what each `select` looks like:

```
<form="myForm" action="" method="post">
<select name="mySelectOne">
    <option value="0">Free</option>
    <option value="1">$1.00</option>
    <option value="2">$2.00</option>
</select>

<select name="mySelectTwo">
    <option value="0">Free</option>
    <option value="1">$1.00</option>
    <option value="2">$2.00</option>
</select>

<select name="mySelectThree">
    <option value="0">Free</option>
    <option value="1">$1.00</option>
    <option value="2">$2.00</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I know I could use `$.when()` to check if my ajax request(s) are complete, but I'm not sure how many I will have.

Right now I'm just using an `$.each` statement to loop through each input.

```
$('#myForm select').each(function (key, elm) {
    ....
    // find out how many request(s) i need to make
    if(totalRequests == ??) {
      // I'm all done
    }
});
```

I have tried to just count how many inputs I have:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
var length = $('#myForm select').length;
var count = 1;

$('#myForm select').each(function (key, elm) {

    onFormSubmit(data, function (result) {
     // handle response
    });

    count++;

    if(count == length) {
       // all done.
    }
});

});


var onFormSubmit = function(callback){
    // ajax stuff
}
```

Which is fine if I was always going to make three requests. I may only have two...or maybe only one. In that case, `length` is not very reliable.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

**EDIT**

I have updated my js as @freakish has suggested:

```
var reqs = [];
var skipArray = ['123', '456']; // input values that equal no charge

$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    $('#myForm select').each(function (key, elm) {
        $elm = $(elm);

          if ($.inArray($elm.val(), skipArray) !== -1) {
              // No charge.
          } else {
               reqs.append(onFormSubmit(data, function (result) {
                   console.log(result);
               }));
          }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});



var onFormSubmit = function(data, callback){
    // ajax call
}
```

Comment: And why do you have multiple ajax requests, wouldn't it be easier to just send the value of all three dropdowns in one request

Comment: The server I am sending the data to can only accept one argument at a time. I can't send it an array or anything like that. So, I need to send multiple requests.

Comment: Note that your HTML is totally invalid btw.

Comment: And you could probably do something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/accafaas/

Comment: What triggers this ajax? Not entirely clear what you are trying to do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your selects, make a request (if necessary) and use `$.when` like this:

```
var reqs = [];

$('#myForm select').each(function (key, elm) {
    // some stuff
    if (condition) {
        reqs.push(
            $.ajax(
                // the request
            )
        );
    }
}

$.when.apply($, reqs).then(function() {
    // when all done
});
```

The trick is to use `.apply` to make it dynamic.

Note that if `reqs` is empty then `.then` will trigger as well.

Comment: Hi @freakish, thank you! I think I understand what you are suggesting, but I don't quite follow. `reqs` is an array of ajax requests? Then I'm using `apply` to init the array (of ajax posts). 

Currently I get `reqs.append is not a function`. I have updated my post to reflect what I have updated.

Comment: @Damon Ahh, sorry, it's been a while since I coded in JavaScript. Should've been `.push` instead of `.append`. Too much Python, you use `.append` there. :D

Comment: @Damon Just remember that your `onFormSubmit` function has to return `return $.ajax(...);` object.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was just the shove I needed.